# run php as lower version

Tags: php, apache

I have a local development server and a remote server.

The remote server runs php 5.4, my local server runs XAMPP with php 5.6.

I originally wrote the the php for 5.6, but there are some scripts that produce an error in 5.4.

The obvious solution would be to install XAMPP with php 5.4 locally, but I have multiple site development projects on my computer, some of which which are written in 5.6 and are deployed on 5.6.

Is there a way to make 5.6 at least act like 5.4 so I can test the site locally and find all the errors before deployment?

I thought putting 'AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php' in my root .htaccess might work but it didn't.

Comment: You can add [legacy behavior](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) to your code, so it will change it's functions depending on which version of PHP it's running on.

Comment: There are syntax changes and some new functions between the two versions. If you have to run the code on PHP 5.4, you will unfortunately have to give up a few (although not too many) of the newer features.

Comment: PHP 5.4 EOL just happened. There isn't even security support for that version anymore. You should migrate.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/123902/getting-xampp-to-work-with-multiple-version-of-php you can install multiple versions of php in XAMPP

Comment: You can make multiple installation of XAMP, especially using the portable version. XAMPP support also switching version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make 5.6 act like 5.4. 
You must have to done changes in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible.

Think about using virtualization for easy multiple environments.
Vagrant is tool for that, after installation only one command like `vagrant up` gives you ready to use LAMP server, you can deploy multiple VM with different PHP versions etc.